# How to use same python cgi file on windows and linux (apache)?

Tags: python, linux, windows, apache, cgi

Using python as CGI on linux/apache server, The first line (one that defines the interpreter, shebang) should be like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Running same python CGI on windows/apache server, the first line (one that defines the interpreter) should be like this: (assuming that python installed to c:/python27)

```
#!c:/python27/python.exe
```

Is there option to set identical line so that no changes will be needed while moving files from linux to windows?

Comment: You may look at the answer about perl shebang on windows:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036577/how-do-i-ignore-the-perl-shebang-on-windows-with-apache-2

Comment: Please do not add "solved" to your question title. If you figured out a solution of your own, please post it as an answer and [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/220538) by clicking the check mark in the left margin.

Comment: @GuyDafny: Please read my comment carefully. I said "Please do **not** add "solved" to your question title ...". :)

Comment: @Amal Murali: Thanks again, Sorry - English isn't my native language, I've tried to read too fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full answer described here:
[http://my.opera.com/NoteMe/blog/running-python-as-cgi-in-apache-in-windows](https://web.archive.org/web/20140301021052/http://my.opera.com/NoteMe/blog/running-python-as-cgi-in-apache-in-windows)

Under Windows - Next changes to the apache config file:

```
AddHandler cgi-script .py
```

remove the "hash" ("#") from the next line:

```
#ScriptInterpreterSource Registry
```

More details and some additional data about security in this case can be found here:
[How do you use the Apache "ScriptInterpreterSource Registry-Strict" directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379930/how-do-you-use-the-apache-scriptinterpretersource-registry-strict-directive)

Answer (score 2):

So you have the shebang line `#!/usr/bin/env python`
What you are missing in Windows is literally the **env.exe** application.

1. Download the following ZIP files from the GnuWin project
   https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/coreutils/5.3.0/:

   - **coreutils-5.3.0-bin.zip**
   - **coreutils-5.3.0-dep.zip**
2. Create **\usr\bin** folder on the same drive, where Apache HTTP for Windows starts from, for example: `c:\usr\bin`
3. Extract into created \usr\bin folder:

   - **env.exe** from coreutils-5.3.0-bin.zip;
   - **libiconv2.dll, libintl3.dll** from coreutils-5.3.0-dep.zip
4. You should have the following files there:

   ```
   C:\usr\bin>dir
    Volume in drive C is OSDisk
    Volume Serial Number is DEAD-BEEF

    Directory of C:\usr\bin

   01/23/2019  10:24 AM    <DIR>          .
   01/23/2019  10:24 AM    <DIR>          ..
   04/20/2005  01:41 PM            24,064 env.exe
   03/16/2004  03:37 PM           898,048 libiconv2.dll
   10/09/2004  11:25 AM           101,888 libintl3.dll
                  3 File(s)      1,024,000 bytes
   ```

Bingo! Now your Apache will interpret the shebang line correctly.

## A bonus step

For those who would like to **run Python CGI scripts from Python virtual environment**.

5. If you have Python virtual environment created in `c:\py-venv`, add the following lines into an Apache httpd.conf for a directory where your Python CGI scripts will be located. The scripts will be executed by Apache using Python virtual environment's binaries and modules.

   ```
   # Python virtual environment folder
   Define VENV "c:/py-venv"
   # Python CGI scripts location
   Define PY_CGI "c:/test/cgi"

   <Directory "${PY_CGI}">
       AllowOverride None
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
       Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks
       Options -Indexes
       Require all granted
       SetEnv VIRTUAL_ENV ${VENV}
       SetEnv PATH "${VENV}/Scripts;${PATH}"
   </Directory>
   ```